# Add a ProgressBar to ListView items in LargeIcon mode

Tags: c, listview, winapi, progress-bar

Is there a way to add a ProgressBar to ListView items in LargeIcon mode, for example:

[image]

The ProgressBar can be the default Windows ProgressBar control, or it can be of a single color as shown in the image.

Comment: I guess as workaround: 1.- Use a custom control with ListView and maybe an ownerdraw progressbar. 2.- Dump WinAPI and use a C framework like gtk which can be more easy achive what you want. 3.- Move from C and use another language framework like Qt or WxWidgets which they have already a custom control like those.

Comment: @Joel This is not hard in winapi

Comment: This is pretty easy to do with an owner-drawn ListView and some custom drawing logic to draw an image and a colored rectangle underneath it.

Comment: @Joel For what it's wroth it'll be roughly the same amount of work in GTK+ due to having to play around with cell layouts and cell renderers and GtkIconView being somewhat fickle (maybe slightly easier in more recent versions with GtkFlowBox but YMMV). In my opinion, if you have this much code already, just stay with the Windows API.